# Kotlin view object full type name in Android studio in mac OS

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, keyboard-shortcuts

I am reading the book `Android Development in Kotlin` and there is a shortcut to view the type of an object in Kotlin.

Windows: `Shift + Ctrl + P`
and Mac: `arrow key + control + P`

I cannot seem to get it working on a mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the symbol of `⇧` with `↑`. `Shift` in mac can be represented by `⇧`. So, you may try `Ctrl + Shift + P` in mac also.

If it doesn't work, you may go to `Setting -> Keymap` and search for *Expression type*. Here, you can check out the shortcut and change it by right clicking the shortcut, then *Add Keyboard Shortcut*.
[image]

Besides, `Ctrl + Q` also shows the type of an object.